# Simple Binary Semaphore implementation in Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, mutex, semaphore

I'm trying to implement a simple binary semaphore, to protect a critical variable from incorrect values, as so:

```
sem_init(&phore, 0, 1);//sem_t phore;
```

which is locking and realesing here:

```
    void doc(){
  sem_wait(&phore);
  stats->npaten++;
  sem_post(&phore);
  printf("Doctor %d ready for duty\n%d\n",getpid(),stats->npaten);
}
```

`doc` being the worker function of 10 processes and `npaten` a variable of a structure in shared memory.
The expected value for npaten should be 10, however it prints out 1 everytime. Thanks in advance

EDIT: the structure in question:

```
struct stats{
  int nptri;
  int npaten;
  float inicio;
  float fim;
  float avgtime;
}*stats;
```

and shared memory initialization:

```
void sharedmemory(){
  shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(struct stats),IPC_CREAT|0766);
  stats = (struct stats *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
  if(shmid == -1){
    perror("Couldn't create shared memory segment\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if(stats == (struct stats *)-1){
    perror("Couldn't attach shared memory segment to the adress space\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("Shared memory created successfully\n");
}
```

Comment: Explain why 10? And where do you expect it to be print out? What is `doc`?

Comment: If `stats` is really in shared memory it should have been a pointer. Without more context it seems like you are *copying* the structure (so the shared data isn't updated on modifications, only your local copy).

Comment: what @Someprogrammerdude said would espacially be relevant if you forked your process. Also you are intializing something named `sem`as a semaphore but you are using something named `phore` as your semaphore. That looks wrong

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i've updated both my code and the post to give you more information

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude messed a bit more with the code, and the problem was exactly what you said, that is , improper use/initialization of a variable in shared memory, which had now been resolved. Thanks.